# Weird wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) error? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem with the object saving. I have this code in the bookmark model:

```
class Bookmark
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :owner_req, type: Mongoid
  field :request_id, type: Mongoid
  field :corsponding_requests, type: Array

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :request
class << self

    def createBookmark ( title)
      bookmark = self.new
      bookmark[:owner_req] = title[:owner_req] #Here's the error
      bookmark[:request_id] = title[:request_id]
      bookmark[:corsponding_requests] = Array.new
      bookmark[:corsponding_requests].push(*title[:corsponding_requests])
      asd
       if bookmark.save
          bookmark
       end
    end

    def getBookmark(t)
      bookmark = find(t)
      if bookmark
        bookmark
      end
    end
    def getAll
      bookmark = self.all
      if bookmark
        bookmark
      end
    end
  end
end
```

request_bookmarked function

```
  bookmark = Hash.new
      req = User.find(session[:user])

      bookmark["owner_req"] = req[:id]
      bookmark["request_id"] = bookmarked_against_Request[:id]
      bookmark["corsponding_requests"] = Array.new
      bookmark["corsponding_requests"] <<  request_bookmarked[:_id]
      Bookmark.createBookmark(bookmark)
      if request_bookmarked[:favourites_of] == nil
        request_bookmarked[:favourites_of] = Array.new
        request_bookmarked_2[:favourites_of] = Array.new
      end
      if bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] == nil
        bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] = Array.new
        bookmarked_against_Request[:favourites]= Array.new
      end
      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:_id]
      request_bookmarked[:favourites_of] << bookmarked_against_Request_2[:_id]
      flash[:notice] = "Request has been bookmarked successfully."
    end
    request_bookmarked.update(Hash['favourites' ,request_bookmarked_2[:favourites]])
    bookmarked_against_Request.update(Hash['favourites' ,bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites]])
```

I have tried `self.new (title)` but it still keeps on giving me error.

Here's the screen shot to my error: 
[image: error screenshot]

```
> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0): ()
> home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-1a7bbaabf1f0/lib/mongoid/fields/standard.rb:10:in
> `mongoize'   ()
> home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-1a7bbaabf1f0/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:291:in `typed_value_for'   ()
> home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-1a7bbaabf1f0/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:174:in `block in write_attribute'   ()
> home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-1a7bbaabf1f0/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:26:in
> `_assigning'   ()
> home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-1a7bbaabf1f0/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:170:in `write_attribute'  app/models/bookmark.rb:14:in `createBookmark' 
> app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:217:in `bookmark_request' 
> actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
> >`send_action'  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'  actionpack
> (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
> >`process_action'  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in >process_action' 
> activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call' 
> activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in
> >halting_and_conditional'  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in
> >halting_and_conditional'  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in >halting'
```

Comment: post the error trace as well.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my error @shivam

Comment: title is not a attribute. It's a hash in which owner_req, request_id and corsponding_req is present @Deep

Comment: @james in screenshot you are doing `bookmark = self.new(title)` and in ques above `bookmark = self.new` . Which one should I believe?

Comment: I have tried both but both give the same error@shivam

Comment: both errors cant be same. Please paste the exact backtrace of error for above code here.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to print the backtrace @shivam

Comment: ok no problem, reproduce the error and check the terminal window which is running your rails server. Read the logs there, you will find the exact error trace. paste the relevant part at the end of your question.

Comment: @shivam I have added the error trace

Comment: post what comes after  ArgumentError too. Atleast 5-6 lines more :)

Comment: as per your backtrace, error originates here: `app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:217:in 'bookmark_request' `

Comment: @shivam I have added the request_bookmark function

Comment: can you point where exactly is line 217

Comment: @shivam this is the line `Bookmark.createBookmark(bookmark)`

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use the initializer?

Comment: `type: Mongoid` on those fields looks weird.

Comment: @FrederickCheung what do you mean in my code or here to point out those lines ?

Comment: In your code - the owner_req and request_id fields (and according to your comment in the source, it is assignment to those fields that is raising an error)

Comment: I tried the assignment too and Model.new(paramter) way to but both give me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you people for your time but I solved my problem. The owner request was to changed to user_id because when I write belongs_to :user it will assume that the attribute name is user_id